# Why is my filtering missing result for RESTCountries API?

Tags: reactjs, filter

```
const filterCountry = (event) => {
    console.log('input', event.target.value)
    const new_countries = countries.filter(country=> country.name.official.includes(event.target.value));
    
    setCountries(new_countries)
  }
```

Above being my filtering function to get  value matching result from Rest Countries API from axios "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all". PROBLEM is: missing results. With input 'sw', I shall have 'Botswana, Swaziland, Sweden, Swizerland', but now only 'Botswana,Eswatini', wrong result. Can you tell where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is case-sensitive.

Convert both the search text and values to lower case first in `filter`.

```
country.name.official.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
```